# Adding a + sign before string casts it to 0, why?

Tags: php

I know this has been asked before but I couldn't think of how to search for it and can't find it in the docs (though I know it's somewhere) ..

Why does `$a` become 0 in this example?

```
$a = "Foo";
echo +$a; // 0 .. and same with echo -$a;
```

Comment: What do you think this code should return?

Comment: So where are we with the question?

Answer (score 5):

Because with the plus (`+`) you say that it is a positive number, so the string gets implicit casted to an int means here: 0.

You can also see this in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax

And a quote from there:

> Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, **optionally preceded by a sign (- or +).**